# VBScript onClick and jQuery Button Click

Tags: jquery, vbscript

I have a page with a bit of VBScript that launches a printer installation when the button is clicked. There is an alert once the script has completed successfully.

I am now trying to add another button click event (possibly using jQuery), that notifies the user that the printer installation has started (on button click). This is due to the fact that it can take anywhere from 20 seconds to a minute for the printer to be installed.

When implementing the following code, I am getting an error that an object is being expected from within the jQuery code block

```
   <script type="text/vbscript">
        function AddP(pName)
            Set WshNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
            WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection pName
            MsgBox "Printer Added"
        end function
   </script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready( function (){ 

            $("#btn").click( function(){

                 alert("Printer Install Started");

            });

         });
    </script>

 <td><a href="#" language="vbscript" onclick="AddP('\\PrinterName')"><input id="btn" name="Button1" type="button" value="Add"></a></td>
```

Comment: It's not valid or a good idea to enclose the button inside the anchor... Why do you need the anchor in the first place.. Just a button is sufficient right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to give the user some indication something is happening while the printer is being added you could change the button state.

```
<script type="text/vbscript">
   function AddP(pName)
       Dim allButton1s
       Set allButton1s = document.getElementsByName("Button1")
       allButton1s(0).value = "Please wait..."
       Set WshNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
       WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection pName
       MsgBox "Printer Added"
       allButton1s(0).value = "Add"
   end function
</script>
```

Comment: this is what I was trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to add Error checking and prompt to set at Default. This is my first real shot at scripting so keep that in mind.

```
<script type="text/vbscript">
function AddP(pName)

Shortname = split(pName, "\")

    If MsgBox("Click YES to install  " &ShortName(3),VBYesNo, "Printer Utility") = vbYes Then

        MsgBox "Installing Printer " &ShortName(3) &vbCrLf &vbCrLf &"This may take a few moments"


        Set WshNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")

        On Error Resume Next
        WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection pName
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then

            MsgBox "Printer is not available for install." &vbCrLF &"Please contact Tech Support for assistance"
                Else If MsgBox ("Would you Like  " &ShortName(3) &" to be your Default Printer?" ,vbyesno, "Printer Utility")  = vbYes Then

                WshNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter pName
                MSgBox ShortName(3) &"  Installed and Set as Default",0,"Printer Utility"
                Else MSgBox ShortName(3) &"  Installed",0,"Printer Utility"

                End if

            End If

        On Error GoTo 0
     Else Msgbox "Printer Install Cancelled"
    End if
end function
```

<  /Script>

Answer (score 0):

If really just want to put up an alert before you start the printer install add another MsgBox line before it

```
<script type="text/vbscript">
   function AddP(pName)
       MsgBox "Printer Install Started"
       Set WshNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
       WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection pName
       MsgBox "Printer Added"
   end function
</script>
```

Note: The printer install won't start until the user hits ok on the "Print Install Started" alert, if you want to avoid that use the button state change answer instead.